# Firebase Google sign in: get user location

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, gidsignin

Is it possible to access a Google user's location once they've signed in (using GIDSignIn)?

I have no trouble accessing a user's name, email, and photo.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is possible,
you can set it as profile properties.

so you get user location normally and set it to users profile in your database

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure if user location is accessible through GIDSignIn but according to their documentation, you can request for [additional scope](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/additional-scopes) of information; aside from the basic info, from the user. [Here's](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/api/interface_g_i_d_sign_in.html#a43386d1f0af8fedf6263e673631a56ca) even more info about it.

Here's the extensive list of Google's current [OAuth 2.0 API Scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had gone through the API scopes, but didn't see anything listed for location (other than fitbit and glass).

Comment: I guess its currently not supported then. When trying to [create a new account](https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?hl=en), location is just the country and looking into your Google account [privacy](https://myaccount.google.com/privacy), location is only activated through your phone. But the [aboutme](https://aboutme.google.com/) page has a Places info field. Probably try getting their location from there.